# PHP MySQL Sum a column IF row have the right timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, sum

i have 1 table with 3 column: id, amount, date 
i want to calculate the amount only if the date is today in PHP with MySQL, i tried with various thing but none of them worked, for calculate the today date i use 
    $date = date('m/d/y');

Comment: Try, `"SELECT SUM(amount) WHERE date = '".date("Y-m-d")."'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN DATE(`date`) = DATE(NOW()) THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
FROM   my_table
```

EDIT:

As suggested in the comments by @user3760540, using [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) could be more elegant:

```
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN DATE(`date`) = CURDATE()) THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: Thank you, it's ok if i change the NOW() with CURDATE()?

Comment: @user3760540 yes! Forgot about that one. It would actually be more elegant that way.